# Ctrl + H = BackSpace in TextBoxes?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, keyboard-shortcuts

If I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> while I'm writing in whatever TextBox of whatever program of mine, the last char written is deleted (like pressing <kbd>BackSpace</kbd>).

WHY?? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> is not a Windows shortcut and I never said in the code to delete the last char pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

How to avoid this?

Comment: CTRL-H is the ASCII `BS` (Backspace) character.

Comment: True, ty! Any idea about how to block ASCII shortcodes in a textbox?

Comment: Why? Doing so would also block BACKSPACE. (They're the same thing.) Ctrl+H sends a backspace character, which is also what the BACKSPACE key sends. Blocking one blocks them both.

Comment: As @KenWhite said, but if you _really_ want to suppress the processing of `BS` you can override it's function by looking for it in the `TextBox_TextChanged()` handler.

Comment: @daShier: Sure you can, but that will also disable the backspace key, which is going to really irk users. I've been writing code for Windows apps since Win 3.1, and have never had a user complain once about Ctrl+H being the same as Backspace. I would have thousands of complaints from users about not being able to backspace over typos - I'd be willing to wager on it.

Comment: 1) It doesn't apply to the RichTextBox control. 2) You can disable (or redefine) it, since `CTRL+H` and `BackSpace` are not exactly the same thing. In `TextBox.KeyDown` you can write: `if e.KeyData = (Keys.Control Or Keys.H) Then e.SuppressKeyPress = true`. This won't affect the BackSpace (`Keys.Back`) functionality.

Comment: @KenWhite I'm not saying _I_ would disable `BS`, I'm only saying it could be done if there was some compelling reason the OP needed to. I can't think of a  reason, but it's not my app. Actually, I  can think of a possible reason: What if the app is a Window replacement for some old legacy app that had a bunch of keyboard shortcuts for which the users had developed muscle memory? It's a stretch, but only the OP knows for sure.

Comment: I complain about Ctrl+H because in one program of mine I have added a low level hook routine. When users press Ctrl+H the low level routine makes its right job... but at the same time is deleted the last char in the text box, also if I have e.handled KeyDown in the low level hook routine. @Jimi: ty! Your simple suggestion works perfectly and BackSpace remains enabled!